# unexpected inheritance of slot (values) using errors

Tags: namespaces, package, common-lisp

```
(defpackage :winner
  (:use :cl)
  (:export e1))

(in-package :winner)

(define-condition e1 ()
  ((name
    :initform "e1"
    :reader name)
   (package 
    :initform "winner"
    :reader related-package)))

(defmethod print-object ((err e1) stream)
  (FORMAT stream "~a~%~a~%" (name err) (related-package err)))


(defpackage :loser
  (:use :cl :winner)
  (:export e2))

(in-package :loser)

(define-condition e2 (e1)
  ((name
    :initform "e2")
   (package
    :initform "loser")))
```

I would now expect:

```
(make-instance 'e1)
e1
winner

(make-instance 'e2)
e2
loser
```

but instead i get

```
(make-instance 'winner:e1)
e1
winner

(make-instance 'loser:e2)
e1
loser
```

which is is quite unexpected. 
What error am I making?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's relatively easy to see if you use `DESCRIBE`.

```
? (make-instance 'loser:e2)
e1
loser

? (describe *)
e1
loser

Class: #<STANDARD-CLASS LOSER:E2>
Wrapper: #<CCL::CLASS-WRAPPER LOSER:E2 #x302000ECE15D>
Instance slots
WINNER::NAME: "e1"
PACKAGE: "loser"
LOSER::NAME: "e2"
```

What you see is that the object has three (!) slots: `WINNER::NAME`, `PACKAGE` and `LOSER::NAME`.

Why is that? `PACKAGE` is a symbol in the package `CL` (`PACKAGE` is a system class, a type, in Common Lisp). Since both your package use CL, the both have the same symbol `PACKAGE` and thus there is only one slot of name `CL:PACKAGE`.

`NAME` is a symbol local to each of your package. Each package has its own symbol name. Thus each object has two different slots `WINNER::NAME` and `LOSER::NAME`.

Since your printer function only reads the slot `WINNER::NAME`, you only get its content.

**What do you need to keep in mind?**

- having a custom printer is fine, but use `DESCRIBE` for debugging
- packages are namespaces for symbols. They are not modules for concepts like classes, slots, functions.
- the package `CL` comes with many symbols. If your packages uses the package `CL`, then it has all these symbols. Whether you use them for function names, variables, class names, slot names, ... does not matter.